# How can I use my built-in AMD Radeon 7670m instead of Intel HD 4000 Graphics?

Tags: switchable-graphics

i recently bought a DELL Inspiron 15R 2012m Series Laptop. It comes with a built-in AMD Radeon 7670m graphics card.

I installed PES 2012, when I checked the system specification (an option in that PES 2012 game ). I came to know that game runs with Intel HD4000 Graphics and not with my AMD card.

I also changed the swithchable graphics and assigned *High Performance* to PES2012, but the game still runs on Intel HD4000.

Answer (score 1):

You must uninstall the AMD driver with Catalyst program and after this, install Catalyst 12.7 beta. This worked for me.